# How to achieve a dynamic RegularExpressionValidator via the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, constructor

I'm building a Custom Control which simply inherits from RegularExpressionValidator.  In the constructor I need to be able to see what the viewstate value of the control is so that I can use that value during the construction to determine which validation expression I need it to use.

The problem is the constructor does not have access to viewstate when it is called. At least viewstate is always null due to the timing when the constructor is called.

I have tried overriding the render method, but for some reason, even though the control has access to the viewstate the base.validationexpression always fails due to it not being assigned in the constructor.

What I have is a public property that looks at the viewstate.

```
public NameType NameValidationType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ViewState["NameType"] == null ? NameType.FirstName : (NameType)ViewState["NameType"];
            }

            set
            {
                this.ViewState["NameType"] = value;
            }
        }
```

This value is always null when the constructor is called.  Is there some way to delay the execution of the constructor to read from viewstate before being constructed?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to get this to work is to build the controls base validationexpression and other attributes in the OnPreRender event.  Render was too late and anything before the OnPreRender did not have access to viewstate.